# How can I speed up Unity with an ATI card?

Tags: unity, ati

I've been using Unity for two days... but all the apps and Unity itself runs very slowly I've installed Catalyst 11.4 (Ati Radeon HD 4350, 2GB RAM, Core 2 Duo @1.86 Ghz, 12 Gb Partition, 1 Gb to Swap) and I unchecked the v blank option in OpenGL in CCSM.

There is another way to speed up unity?

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this which doesn't require CCSM, or which uses Ubuntu-tweak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to CCSM (compiz Configuration Settings Manager) then go to the OpenGL plug in and then uncheck **Sync to Vblank**.

Then go back and on the Composite plug in uncheck **Detect Refresh Rate**

Answer (score 0):

Using ailurus (there is definitely an easier way..) you can change the tendency of swapping memory . Giving it smaller values (default is 60 if i recall correctly , i moved it to 10) would make your system prefer ram over swap - that would increase ram usage but make your system a little faster. Or , at least, that's how it feels on my end.

---

Using less fancy compiz effects would definitely help as well (probably more than the previous idea)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use less fancy compiz effects in Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: For example the fire animation is pretty amazing but uses too much resources in weaker machines - the same probably counts for the wobbly windows plugin etc

i think that it is pretty obvious which ones are fancier and which ones are just plain effects