# Slow desktop performance in Ubuntu 11.04-11.10 with proprietary AMD-drivers

Tags: flash, ati

Forgive my lack of knowledge, but I assumed that the proprietary drivers would be faster. I read somewhere that the use of VESA is much slower and Ubuntu indicates that VESA is used even though the ATI-drivers are recommended by the system. How can I revert back to the Radeon-opensource drivers which are MUCH faster? Even the rendering of the text I type is slow. :-(

Comment: Since there is no answers on this issue, is this a duplicate? If so; could someone kindly reffer to a related topic which describes this particular issue? I have switched to another driver called "X.Org" but it states it is proprietary too (?) The desktop performance is much better with this driver and it its' performance is comparative to that of other operating systems aswell, however, the driver is "Vesa" and it I have never seen it be stated as a native driver. Could someone please sort this out, since I don't know what would be the correct configuration for this graphic card on 11.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I speed up Unity in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39050/how-can-i-speed-up-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the proprietary drivers, do 2 things.

1. install compiz-settings-manager and disable "Sync to VBlank" in the OpenGL plugin, inside ccsm (CompizConfig-Settings-Manager)
2. enable "Tear Free" in the AMD Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: thank you for your time to comment this, but this has had no effect. Sorry.

Comment: @jonas: Disabling the "Sync to VBlank" helped tremendously in my case