# Something Different with ATI Driver?

Tags: drivers, ati

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I speed up Unity with an ATI card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39050/how-can-i-speed-up-unity-with-an-ati-card)

I have ATI radeon HD 4850 and use ati 12.11 Driver on my ubuntu. I've downloaded in AMD official site but the performance reduce when I install it and the performance better before I install it. The installation was successfully and there's no problem when installation. can you tell what's wrong with ATI driver? compiz run, but so slowly when I move the window

Thanks Masters :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it speeded up ATI performance by UNchecking Sync To VBlank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Install compizconfig-settings-manager if you don't already have it. Run it. Select the OpenGL applet. Check "Sync to VBlank".

PS - My mistake. "Sync to VBlank should be UNchecked.